# Cannot assign "<JobImages: Logo Logo>": "JobImages.job" must be a "Job" instance

Tags: django

Here is my code:

class JobImagesCreateView(CreateView):

```
 template_name = 'jobs/job_images.html'
    form_class = JobImageCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("dashboard")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        job = form.save()
        images = self.request.FILES.getlist("more_images")
        for i in images:
            JobImages.objects.create(job=job, image=i)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: can you share JobImageCreateForm

Comment: class JobImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    more_images = forms.FileField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "multiple": True
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = JobImages
        fields = '__all__'

Comment: had a stab at it do you have the Job Images model code? maybe I can be more specific as to the solution, if you're struggling, once I have that.

Comment: class JobImages(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='attachments', blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.job.job_title

Comment: comment you should put this an dthe other object in your qeustion. My answer below applies as you're assigning the wrong model object job = form.save() will return an JobImages model, not a Job model. Consider a customer endpoint for the job. i.e. path('job/<job_id>/image-upload, your_view, name="your.url") then you get the job from the job_id and use that to get the Job model object and make the correct assignment